# In Java, how do I get a list of audio file types that can be read?

Tags: java, audio, file-io

I want to make a file chooser in Java for reading audio files. How do I get a list of file extensions for audio file types that can be read by `javax.sound.sampled`? I don't want to hard-code it because I might add providers for more file types later, or it might differ on different systems.

I know I can use `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` but it turns out this only lists file types that can be written by the system. But I have added SPI for other audio formats which provide read, but not write capability.

I also think I can get a list of all the providers of `javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader` with:

```
ServiceLoader<AudioFileReader> readerLoader = ServiceLoader.load(AudioFileReader.class);
```

But I don't know how to see for each provider which file type its for.

So is there a method equivalent to `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` that shows what file types can be read, or how would I code this method?

Comment: How is this still unanswered almost ten years later?
I have this exact problem.